# What is the value of ul (User Language) in Google Analytics Measurement protocol

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

I am building a server side application that needs to report data to GA via Measurement Protocol.

I want to fill the languages that the user have, from the documentation:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#ul

It seems the right parameter is called ul and an example value is en-us.

My questions are:

1. which kind of langague identifier it accepts? the documentation isn't clear on that. My guess is that following the "en-us" example suggests it is based on Accept-Language header so probably ISO-639-1 +ISO-3166)
2. It only has space for 20 bytes, so does it means you can't send multiple langagues?
3. Does the reporting show multiple languages?

Comment: In a web setting User Language is actually the  set browser language, of which there is only one at a time. Just out of curiosity, what would be the use case for multiple languages ? I doubt GA will care what you enter as value, so in theory you could send a list, but you will not be able do do a breakdown by list items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you goto `Google Analytics Dashboard -> Audience -> Geo -> Language` and hover over the help icon next to `language` column you get this popup -

[image]

It apparently uses [ISO 639](https://www.iso.org/iso-639-language-codes.html?hl=en_US) language codes.

2. Only one language can be sent per hit. It is not a multi value property.
3. (2) above makes it obvious what reports can show
4. In the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#ul) (as of aug '18), the following is shown:

> Optional. Specifies the language.

```
Parameter Value | Type | Default Value | Max Length | Supported Hit Types 
ul                text   None            20 Bytes     all
```

> Example value: en-us 
>   Example usage: ul=en-us

Comment: It is also worth noting that actually you can send whatever you want and it will still work.